# Angular HttpModule - hide browser's console error messages for status != 200

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

How to properly handle requests in my Angular frontend? In my node.js API, I always send status 404 if the requested resource was not found. But sending this, cause a error message to appear in the console as you can see in the following image.

[image: browse'rs console error]

**What should I do to hide this message from the browser's console?**

I think a possible solution could be send status 200 for all requests, but with custom error messages and empty arrays for the requested resources.. Someone can give me a light here?

**Obs: I'm currently handling eventually errors like this:**

> service.ts

```
  return this.http.get(url, options).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError),
    map(response => {
      return response['data'] || [];
    })
  )

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the error and then you can do something with the error:

```
return this.http.get(url, options).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError),
    map(response => {
      return response['data'] || [];
    })
    .catch((e: any) => console.log(e));
  )
```

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'?

Answer (score 0):

```
flatMap((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
   if (error.status != 200) {
     return throwError(error)
   } else {
     return new Observable<void>(observer => observer.complete());
   }
})
```